# export to excel from asp.net value converts to date

Tags: export-to-excel

I am exporting some values from datagrid to excel. My problem is values like 2-3, 3-4 is converted in to date format - 3-Feb,4-March etc.

Please advice how to fix this? I tried setting the column format to text only but it is not working.

Regards
V

Answer (score 1):

Inside the grid rowdatabound function you have to set the format of the cells as below

```
 e.Row.Cells(4).Attributes.Add("style", "vnd.ms-excel.numberformat:@")
```